# How to retrive Column name and datatype from \d in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am new to Postgresql and working on a project which takes snapshot of relation.I want to retrive the first 2 column name and datatype from \d+ command in postgresql and then use this result to create a another table with only first 2 column 
I am stuck on this . Can someone guide me on this ?

```
Column    |            Type             |                         Modifiers                          | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 i            | integer                     |                                                            | plain    |              | 
 updated_time | timestamp without time zone | default '2000-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone | plain    |              | 
 version      | numeric                     | default '0'::numeric                                       | main     |              | 
 is_updated   | boolean                     | default false                                              | plain    |              | 
 name         | character varying(20)       |                                                            | extended |              |
```

Comment: why \d meta command? why not sql?.., like `create table nnn as select a,b from mmm`

Comment: \d give the column name and datatype of a relation .So i need to fetch only the first 2 column name and datatype and then use this to create a another relation

Comment: believe, plpgsql will be much easier here

Comment: create table nnn as select a,b from mmm  , but here a and b will be static . What i have done is I create A realtion T with all column and appended 3 column for snapshot logic (automtaically). Now i need to show the result to user but only with column which user has specified (leaving automatic columns one) Your example is not generic .

Comment: look into query in my answer - you control column list in `where` clause - I used <=2 to take first two

Answer (score 1):

I would just use plPgSql here, eg:

```
t=# do
$$
begin
execute format('create table so as select %s from pg_database',(select string_agg(column_name,',') from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'pg_database' and ordinal_position <=2));
end;
$$
;
DO
t=# \d so
     Table "public.so"
 Column  | Type | Modifiers
---------+------+-----------
 datname | name |
 datdba  | oid  |

t=# \d pg_database
    Table "pg_catalog.pg_database"
    Column     |   Type    | Modifiers
---------------+-----------+-----------
 datname       | name      | not null
 datdba        | oid       | not null
 encoding      | integer   | not null
 datcollate    | name      | not null
 datctype      | name      | not null
 datistemplate | boolean   | not null
 datallowconn  | boolean   | not null
 datconnlimit  | integer   | not null
 datlastsysoid | oid       | not null
 datfrozenxid  | xid       | not null
 datminmxid    | xid       | not null
 dattablespace | oid       | not null
 datacl        | aclitem[] |
Indexes:
    "pg_database_datname_index" UNIQUE, btree (datname), tablespace "pg_global"
    "pg_database_oid_index" UNIQUE, btree (oid), tablespace "pg_global"
Tablespace: "pg_global"
```

**update**

the above is easily modifiable for other options if needed,eg:

```
t=# drop table so;
DROP TABLE
t=# do
$$
begin
execute format('create table so (%s) ',(select string_agg(column_name||' '||data_type||' '||case when is_nullable = 'NO' then 'NOT NULL' else '' end,',') from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'pg_database' and ordinal_position <=2));
end;
$$
;
DO
t=# \d so
     Table "public.so"
 Column  | Type | Modifiers
---------+------+-----------
 datname | name | not null
 datdba  | oid  | not null
```

to include some modifiers...

**update2**

lastly if you want to use exact result from `\d` meta command - you can build you dinamic query from the one used by `psql` for `\d`:

```
-bash-4.2$ psql -E -c "\d pg_database"
********* QUERY **********
SELECT c.oid,
  n.nspname,
...
```

and so forth

Comment: And how will i access modifier also , along with column name and datatype ?

Comment: updated the answer.. but you could just query to check yourself

Comment: i tried this , but i am getting error near exceute format . This is not supported in postgresql ryt ?

Comment: Any help if i can copy content of \d+ tablename content to the file and then retrieve my desired things ?

Comment: i mean does "excuete format " is supported un Postgresql.

Comment: Is there any way of doing above in postgre 6.0 version . Beacuse execute format is not supported in this . And i cant update it as  current version is only allowed in my project

Comment: I already checked https://www.postgresql.org/docs/6.4/static/sql-commands.htm for `FORMAT` and indeed did not find it, neither plpgsql

Comment: i just used this                                                                                                     begin
execute format('create table so as select %s from pg_database',(select string_agg(column_name,',') from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'pg_database' and ordinal_position <=2));
end;